# Start Rails 3 server with Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project

I have a Rails 3 project, and I have a computer with Rails 2 installed. Is there any way for me to start the server on that computer? I cannot update the computer to Rails 3 for various reasons.

Comment: If you have bundler, then run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` and `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: Could you install additional versions? There are ways (like rvm) to run them parallel.

Comment: No I cant really change anything except the project itself, I dont have admin rights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'update the computer to rails 3', you can install multiple versions of rails concurrently and define which versions to use in each project.

- In Rails 2 projects the rails version is defined by `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` in environment.rb
- In Rails 3 projects the rails version is defined by `gem 'rails', '3.x.x'` in the gemfile

If you also need multiple ruby versions:

- If on linux have a look at [RVM](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm)
- if on windows have a look at [pik](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/pik/)

Comment: I see, but I dont admin rights on this computer so I cant really change anything on the computer, only the project itself

Comment: You'll just run into error after error if you run the rails 3 project against rails 2 (by changing the rails version number in the gemfile), but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886921/downgrading-a-rails-3-app-to-rails-2) for some downgrade guidance.